# Should I create a separate login page or just a popup from the sign up page?

Tags: user-behavior, user-expectation, login

A popup would be more easy for me. It saves me from having to make another page. This being said, on *average*, which method does a user prefer more? A popup may be faster, but do users feel it is as secure or fun?

Comment: I prefer a login page because a pop up doesn't allow me to click on my 1password toolbar icon. If I go to the toolbar the pop up hides under the main window. What Juan said below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will suggest you go with popup.

**The reason:** 
Take an example of http://www.amazon.in/ - it takes you to a new page when you click on 'sign in' page. On the other hand http://www.flipkart.com/ offers you a popup for login.

Now take a scenario that you are searching for some product and after spending some time you finally find the product you want to 'Add to cart or buy' and then you click on sign-in button on Amazon and it takes you to a new page. Suddenly, the product you wanted to buy is not in your view. Amazon redirects you to your previous page after login - but that's after login or giving a user a sense of fear that he/she has to look for the product again.

In case of Flipkart (popup) the user stays on the same page while logging in without the fear of losing the page/product.

If you are thinking about security - popup or new page doesn't make much difference if the URL is starting with '**https**'

Answer (score 0):

Personally the way I'd do it is to create a login page. On that page you'd present the user with their login fields and a hyperlinked option that says something like:

*"Not already a member? Sign up now."*

When they click on the above link, presenting the user with a pop-up window would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I would argue for the page. A popup might require technologies which are not available to everyone (say, using plugins or certain Javascript code on mobile) or make it less accessible. In general, using a page seems like a reduced cognitive load for the user, if login is absolutely required, since the intent of the page is crystal clear: " Ah, I have to sign in or register to continue". As a corollary, minimize this requirement as much as possible, so that it does not unnecessarily hinder the user's experience.